# Opening bottled beer early

Tags: recapping

I'm a first time homebrewer and I made the schoolboy error of using my old Peroni beer bottles and caps. The caps haven't really taken well (I assume they're a one-time-only seal) and I've ordered new caps online. I bottled the beer late on Saturday with carbonation drops. The new caps will come Wednesday-friday,so potentially 6 days after original bottling. I'm sure the bottles will be leaking CO2 until then and when I open them to replace the caps they'll lose even more.
So, is the brew ruined or will it carbonate ok over the following week? Should I add another drop to the bottles? Or keep them bottled for 2 weeks from the secondary capping?

Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Recapping after 6 days will be too late.  Bottle carbonation is usually done in about or less than one week at the right temperature. I usually give it a week or two to be on the safe side.  But once it is done, letting the bottle sit for a longer time won't help.

First thing to do is let the bottles carbonate for at least one week.  Then put one bottle in the fridge for a few hours before opening it.  If it is not carbonated correctly, chances are that CO2 has escaped.  You will need to prime your bottles again, but only do this after letting your bottles carbonate for enough time.

If you have some carbonation but not enough, then one carbonation drop could be too much, you will have to decide at that time. Good luck.